# Automatically connect Wired Ethernet Connection after power outage

Tags: linux, networking, internet-connection

I am using Scientific Linux 6.2 (Variant of RHEL / CentOS) . Every day at a particular time there is a power outage at my place, and after 1 hour power is restored. My laptop is connected to a network switch, that has no Backup power, and connection is disconnected when power is gone. Laptop keeps running in battery power.

Now when power is restored, the ethernet connection (eth0) is not automatically restored in linux. It only says connection available under wired connection. The same thing happens to the Wireless Network Connections. What can I do to automatically connect to these networks, whenever they are available?

Comment: does it have a gnome environment???

Comment: yes. gnome 2 environment.

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkManager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) does this automatically.  It is part of RHEL/CentOS so I assume it will be available for Scientific Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have gnome environment, I will give you a GUI solution,

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]